# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/... error

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I just included some Glide libraries and the Gradle builds fine.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0-javadoc.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

But I run into this:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
```

As well as this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Would appreciate any tips on getting this sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two dependencies causing a conflict. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` and `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`

I manually included the `libs/android-support-v4.jar` in the library directory since Glide requires it then removed the `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` dependency. The Gradle synced well after that, and the error was cleared.